# copying same file to other folder multiple times

Tags: php

i using this script to copying files to other folder when i clicked submit button

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['upload']) && isset($_POST['datae'])) {
copy('../print/'.$_POST['datae'], '../Upload/'.$_POST['datae']);
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>";
}
?>
```

and now im wondering what if i choose same filename and submitted twice or more.  normally the filename i've already choose will copy and overwrite the same file  that already stored in there.


but what i want is whenever i submitted twice or more  the file that already in destination folder, it will not replace or overwrite but it will duplicating same file and just different in file name like

```
//example in my folder
img_7878.JPG
img_7878_copy1.JPG
img_7878_copy2.JPG
```

maybe i could get help from here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [uniqid function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) and [pathinfo function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php). Like so (isn't tested):

```
if (isset($_POST['upload']) && isset($_POST['datae'])) {
    $uploadPath = '../Upload/' . $_POST['datae'];
    if (file_exists($uploadPath)) {
         $pathInfo = pathinfo($uploadPath);
         $uniqueId = uniqid('_copy_');
         $uploadPath = $pathInfo['dirname'] . '/' . $pathInfo['filename'] . $uniqueId . '.' . $pathInfo['extension'];
    }
    copy('../print/'.$_POST['datae'], $uploadPath);
}
```

Also there is a potential vulnerability in your code: someone can create any path using a post parameter like:

`$_POST['datae'] = '../../../env_file_with_passwords_file_from_protected_dir'`

To avoid this please read [this doc article](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). In your case you can check file name to be sure that someone doesn't try to stole your file:

```
if (isset($_POST['upload']) && isset($_POST['datae']) && preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_]+\.[a-z0-9_]+$/i', $_POST['datae'])) {
    copy('../print/'.$_POST['datae'], '../Upload/'.$_POST['datae']);
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split the filename on the dot to get the extension seperately and then you can use a while loop to change the targetname until no file for the targetname is found.

Next to that, don't do this: `echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>";`
Use Location.reload();
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

```
    if (isset($_POST['upload']) && isset($_POST['datae'])) {
        $exp = explode('.', $_POST['datae']);
        $targetName = '../Upload/'.$exp[0];
        $ext = $exp[1];
        $target = $targetName .".". $ext;
        $count = 0;
        while (file_exists($target)) {
            $target = $targetName . "_copy". $count .".". $ext;
            $count++;
        }
        copy('../print/'.$_POST['datae'], $target);
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>";
    }
```

Comment: Please note that you must use `fileinfo` or `SplFileInfo` to get the file basename/extension as a file having multiple dots in the name is still valid.